# Density function involving floor function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $Z$ have a uniform distribution on $[−0.5, 0.5]$. Let $X$ be a continuous random variable
which is independent of $Z$. Let$$Y = ⌊X + Z⌋ − Z.$$
I would like to ask how to compute the marginal density function and joint density function of $Y$ and $X-Y$. I have noted that $Y$ may not be an integer because $Y+Z = ⌊X + Z⌋.$ Moreover, I found that for $Y=y$, $$|y-k|<0.5 $$ for some interger $k$. What is the next step or direction to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We begin by considering, for some $y \in \mathbb R$, the set of all $(x, z)$ with $|z| \le 0.5$ such that $$\lfloor x + z \rfloor - z = y. \tag{1}$$  As you noted, this requires that $y+z$ be an integer, and for the sake of convenience, let us restrict the right endpoint of $z$ so that $-0.5 < z \le 0.5$ to avoid issues with uniqueness.  Then it is easy to see that there is a unique $z$ for which $y+z$ is an integer:  specifically, define $[y]$ to be the integer nearest to $y$, with the convention that if $y$ is half an integer, then we round up.  Then $z = [y] - y$.  For example, if $y = 3.1$, then $[y] = 3$ and $z = 3 - 3.1 = -0.1$, and $y + z = 3$; if $y = -2.5$, then $[y] = -2$ and $z = -2 - (-2.5) = 0.5$, and $y + z = -2$.

Having established this, we now require $\lfloor x + z \rfloor = y + z = [y]$.  This is satisfied whenever $$[y] \le x + z < [y] + 1, \tag{2}$$ or $$[y] - z \le x < [y] - z + 1.  \tag{3}$$  Substituting back $z = [y] - y$ we obtain
$$y \le x < y + 1.$$  Therefore, our solution set is $$x \in [y, y+1), \quad z = [y] - y. \tag{4}$$  Hence the density of $Y$ is $$f_Y(y) = \int_{x=y}^{y+1} f_X(x) f_Z([y] - y) \, dx$$ where $f_X$ is the density of $X$ and $f_Z$ is the density of $Z$.  Since the latter is simply uniform on $(-0.5, 0.5]$, $f_Z = 1$ for any valid $y$, and we have
$$f_Y(y) = F_X(y+1) - F_X(y). \tag{5}$$

Let us put this result into practice.  Suppose $X \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(1)$ with density $f_X(x) = e^{-x} \mathbb 1(x \ge 0)$ and CDF $$F_X(x) = (1 - e^{-x}) \mathbb 1 (x \ge 0). \tag{6}$$  Then according to $(5)$ we have $$f_Y(y) = F_X(y+1) - F_X(y) = (1 - e^{-(y+1)}) \mathbb 1 (y \ge -1) - (1 - e^{-y}) \mathbb 1 (y \ge 0). \tag{7}$$  Written piecewise, this is
$$f_Y(y) = \begin{cases} 0, & y < -1 \\ 1 - e^{-(y+1)}, & -1 \le y < 0 \\ (e-1)e^{-(y+1)}, & y \ge 0. \end{cases} \tag{8}$$

You can easily verify this result with simulation.  Here I have plotted a histogram of $10^6$ realizations of $Y$ generated from an exponential distribution for $X$ and a uniform distribution for $Z$, and overlaid it with equation $(8)$.  The result is in extremely close agreement.

[image]